# What is the expression/common form to express that one will stay long term somewhere?

Tags: clarity

Say I've briefly lived somewhere but now I want to return and stay there longer. Here is a paragraph of how I express it. Please suggest improvements.

> The new development looks really awesome. I had a brief stint (1 year) in town XXXXX  in 2003 -2004 at Great Bears development, shortly after it had been built. Loved it, but decided to move. With the emergence of this development, I just might sojourn to XXXXX once again, hopefully, **for longer term**.

Comment: Critique questions here need to include specific questions about the writing, as required by this site's [critique guidelines](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/166/26). I'm closing this for now, but please feel free to edit this question so we can consider re-opening it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to imply that you would consider staying there permanently, I'd suggest

> With the emergence of this development, I just might sojourn to XXXXX once again, hopefully *to settle down there*.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways you could answer this, but it really depends on what you are trying to convey. Most of the responses so far assume you intend to stay permanently. If instead you want to describe the possibility of staying without committing to a duration, you could try something like this:

I just might sojourn there again. This time I might even give it enough time to make me want to plant some roots.